# Drawing with mouse

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, mousemove

Hey guys I need help I am trying to make a program where I can draw in a window with the mouse. So far I have it to where when I click a dot appears but I need to add a drag method so that when I drag the mouse across the page it draws stuff. Can someone look at my code and help me out where you can?

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class mouse {
    private static int x,y;
    private static draw object = new draw ();
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Mouse");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.add(object);
        object.addMouseListener(new AL());
    }
    static class AL extends MouseAdapter{
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        object.drawing(x, y);
      }
      public void mouseDragged( MouseEvent e) {
        x= e.getX();
        y= e.getY();
        object.drawing(x, y);
      }
    }
}
```

and

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class draw extends JPanel {
    private static int x,y;
    public void drawing (int xx, int yy){
        x=xx;
        y=yy;
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea that I have is to add your mouse coordinates each to a separate list whenever the mouse is clicked and draw based on the size of the lists, however since you are using mouse dragged you could just use `Path2D.lineTo(x, y)` and use `e.getX()` and `e.getY()` for the x and y coords. After this use `Path2D.moveTo(x, y)` to make sure line path is appended for each pixel the mouse moves (this makes sure that each movement doesn't look like a straight line, but rather like a line moving whatever direction you're "drawing" in). Also, a few tips:

1. The void `mouseDragged` usually works better when used in `mouseMotionAdapter` because from my experience it usually doesn't register the event in just `mouseAdapter`.
2. Since this is a drawing program, personally I'd set a variable for the size of your circle to be used in the future if you actually are planning to expand this into something bigger (example: g.fillOval(x, y, brushSize, brushSize)).